# Errorbars in Plotnine

Tags: python, plotnine

I have the following Python plotnine code:

```py
    ggplot(df)
    + geom_point(aes("Distance", "Force"), size=2)
    + geom_path(aes("xfit", "yfit"))
```

Where Distance, Force, xfit, and yfit are just lists of values from my dataframe.

That produces this plot:

[image]

I am trying to add error bars to all the points. The way to do this seems to be using: `+ geom_errorbar()` which in R with ggplot2 is very straightforward: `geom_errorbar(ymin = Length - yerr, ymax = Length + yerr)`. However, I haven't been able to get it to work in python with plotnine, and there don't seem to be any code examples using errorbars.

[Here is the documentation on the function](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom_errorbar.html#plotnine.geoms.geom_errorbar). I didn't find it helpful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TyberiusPrime](https://github.com/TyberiusPrime) on GitHub answered the question [here.](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/268) I'll paste the answer below in case it disappears from GitHub for some reason. The question I asked there was the exact as here same.

It's just as straight forward in plotnine, using strings instead of alternative evaluation. Note that you have defined your aes on the geom_point and not on the plot, so you have to tell the error bar about the x values.

```py
from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Distance": [1,2,3], 'Force': [4,5.5,6], 'yerr': [0.1, 0.5, 3]})
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes("Distance", "Force"), size=2) + geom_errorbar(aes(x="Distance", ymin="Force-yerr",ymax="Force+yerr"))
```

[image: plot with errorbars]